# Cant set particluar custom font to button

Tags: java, android

I Have a problem when setting a custom font to a button. This is the code I am using:

```
Typeface typface=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/Epistolar.ttf");       
Button play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
play.setTypeface(typface);
```

The font is located in `assets/fonts`.

I tried using another font and the code works, the font was changed. I checked if i typed it correctly, I checked everything. The question is `why doesn't the other font work? What are the reasons for a font not to work?`.

The particular font I am trying to use is `http://www.dafont.com/epistolar.font`

`FIX :`

I found the same Epistolar font on DeviantArt. In the ZIP I downloaded beside the TTF font there was an OTF font. I Put the OTF font instead of the TTF font I had before in my project and it worked.

Comment: What error are you receiving?

Comment: @Hank G I am not receiving any errors. I just end up with regular font. The font is not changed. I checked the font on Microsoft Word and it doesn't look like the regular font in my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the same Epistolar font on DeviantArt. In the ZIP I downloaded beside the TTF font there was an OTF font. I Put the OTF font instead of the TTF font I had before in my project and it worked.